# How to fix this issue with the UIResponder as not recognized?

Tags: swift, uiresponder

I'm making a NotePad application in Swift and I get the following issue:

> type 'Notification.Name' (aka 'NSNotification.Name') has no member 'UIResponder'

Those are the lines of code I typed on:

```
@objc func updateTextView (notification : Notification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

    let keyboardEndFrameScreenCoordinates = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let keyboardEndFrame = self.view.convert(keyboardEndFrameScreenCoordinates, to: view.window)

    if notification.name == Notification.Name.UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification {
        textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    } else {
        textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardEndFrame.height, right: 0)
        textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = textView.contentInset
    }

    textView.scrollRangeToVisible(textView.selectedRange)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification {

...
```